# PHP not receiving data from $.ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm not sure where my code is going wrong, but I'm trying to pass a JS variable to PHP and it works on the JS side (fires the success message and other console logs properly) but not on the PHP side. I checked the network tab and the status code renders 200 OK, and under form data, it shows the correct data, but it won't print the variable in PHP

here's the JS:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    var email = "testingmore@gmail.com";
    var settings = {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/",
        "data": {
            "email": email,
            "emailType": "Html",
            "status": "Subscribed"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("successfully");
        }
    };

    console.log(settings);

    $.ajax(settings);
</script>
```

and the php:

```
<?php
    $email = isset($_POST['email']);
    if( $email ) {
        print_r($_POST['email']);
    } else {
        echo 'nada<br>';
    }
?>
```

So the print_r never fires, and when I try to print out `$_POST['email']` by itself, it prints out nothing.

Comment: Does it work if you POST to that URL using another method (i.e. an HTML form or a REST client like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/))?

Comment: **Danger** You are using an out of date and unsupported version of jQuery that probably has known security issues. Upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: `isset($_POST['email'])` < that will always be set.

Answer (score -1):

You are making an HTTP request with JavaScript.

The response to that request will be made available to JavaScript.

It is in the `data` variable of the success function that you are ignoring.

You need to do something with that variable.

Alternatively you could use a regular form submission instead of Ajax, in which case the response to the request will be shown as a new page.